# Python ftplib getaddrinfo error with parsed url

Tags: python, urllib, ftplib

I've created a function that is supposed to download files from this particular ftp serwer: `ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/products/bias/2013` where user only gives a year that intrests him. I'm trying to parse server address and I think It is done how it should be (printed versions seem ok), but I'm still getting this: `[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed` and my question is why?

```
sinex_domain = "ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/products/bias/2013"

def download(sinex_domain):
    user = getpass.getuser()
    sinex_parse = urlparse(sinex_domain)

    sinex_connetion = FTP(sinex_parse.scheme+'.'+sinex_parse.netloc)
    sinex_connetion.login()
    sinex_connetion.cwd(sinex_parse.path)
    sinex_files = sinex_connetion.nlst()
    sinex_userpath = "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\DCBviz\\sinex"
    pathlib.Path(sinex_userpath).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    for fileName in sinex_files:
        local_filename = os.path.join(sinex_userpath, fileName)
        file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
        sinex_connetion.retrbinary('RETR '+ fileName, file.write, 1024)
            
        file.close()

    sinex_connetion.quit()

download(sinex_domain)
```

Comment: `ftp.domain` isn't a known hostname; the netloc should be enough for the connection I think.

Comment: and it did, thanks!